# Proc_open returning stdout and never returning stderr

Tags: php

I'm building an API, at some point of the class I've created a `cmd` function that executes the following:

```
public function cmd($cmd)
{
    $return_array   = [];
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin
        1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout
        2 => array("pipe", "w"), // stderr
    );
    //Comando, array con gli std[] e pipes
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

    if (is_resource($process)) {
        //Esegue $cmd: stdin
        fputs($pipes[0], "");
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        //Se in risposta c'è stdout
        while ($f = fgets($pipes[1])) {
            $arr = array_push($return_array, $f);
        }

        fclose($pipes[1]);
        $this->good($return_array);

        //Se in risposta c'è stderr
        while ($f = fgets($pipes[2])) {
            $arr = array_push($return_array, $f);
        }

        fclose($pipes[2]);
        $this->bad($f);

        //Chiusura del process
        proc_close($process);
    }
}
```

[You can skip the Italian comments]

I then have `good()` and `bad()` functions, to be called respectively on `stdout` and `stderr`. (Amazing function names)

When running this command (looking for a non-existent directory) the API returns `$this->good()`:

```
$this->cmd("if [ -d '/tmp/idontexist' ]; then du -s /tmp/idontexist | cut -d '\t' -f1; else echo 'directory not found' 1>&2; fi");
```

I then understood `stdout` is actually always present so I'm trying to wrap my mind on how to implement the `stderr` to go into `$this->bad()` keeping the `stdout` into `$this->good()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but in your processing of `stderr`, you have...

```
//Se in risposta c'è stderr
while ($f = fgets($pipes[2])) {
    $arr = array_push($return_array, $f);
}

fclose($pipes[2]);
$this->bad($f);
```

So this is adding the output from `stderr` to `$return_array` and then your passing the last line of text in `$f` (which will just contain `false` as it's the end of file) to...

```
$this->bad($f);
```

You may want to use a different array to your `stdout` processing, so try...

```
//Se in risposta c'è stderr
$errors = [];
while ($f2 = fgets($pipes[2])) {
    array_push($errors, $f2);
}

fclose($pipes[2]);
$this->bad($errors);
```

**Edit**

Also you should check the returning array content and execute `bad()` and `good()`only if they actually contain something:

```
fclose($pipes[1]);
if(count($return_array)){
    $this->good($return_array);
}

//Se in risposta c'è stderr
while ($f2 = fgets($pipes[2])) {
    $arr = array_push($errors, $f2);
}

fclose($pipes[2]);
if(count($errors)){
    $this->bad($errors);
}
```

Comment: Your hint was very correct, and I'm ashamed for my stupid mistake. Also `good()` as last line exits the code so the `$pipe[2]` while was never executed.